# php Warning: strtotime() Error

Tags: php, string, wordpress, joomla, phpmyadmin

I have changed my joomla and wordpress files from old server to new server. In the front end and admin side its working without any errors. But in the Database (phpmyadmin) Section it shows some warning messages like this..

```
Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. 
You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. 
In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.
We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for 'IST/5.0/no DST' instead in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/db_info.inc.php on line 88

Warning: strftime() [function.strftime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.
We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for 'IST/5.0/no DST' instead in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.lib.php on line 1483
```

Can you please suggest, how to hide these warning messages??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ***Note:*** The `php-cli`'s `php.ini` file is different then `apache2`'s `php.ini` file. I suggest symbolic linking one to another to keep them in sync and avoid confusion!

Answer (score 5):

Do you really just want to hide the error message or do you want to solve the problem, they're indicating?

On your new server, you should find a setting `date.timezone` in your `php.ini` file commented out. Here, you have to specify the timezone your server is located in. For instance, my server is located in Germany, so I use `Europe/Berlin` here:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```

You find a complete list of supported timezones here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

After changing this setting, restart your web server and the warnings should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

See how to use error_reporting, http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

The best way is setting a default Time Zone.
In config.inc.php file, insert one line with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

In my case I use "America/Sao_Paulo" in your case I think is "Asia/Calcutta"

For more details about Time Zones, visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

try this PHP code may be your problem has solve ...