# Unable to change date format in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have tried to change the date "31/01/2015 11:33:22 AM" into "2015-01-31 11:33:22" in PHP

I have tried

```
echo strtotime('31/01/2015 11:33:22 AM');
```

But its throws error ..any thoughts . please share

Error message

> Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EST/-5.0/no DST' instead on line 2

Comment: use `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` before `strtotime() ` function, [Same Question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978751/php-warning-strtotime-error)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should set your timezone, like the warning already told you:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Then, you should take a look at [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), under the `Localized Notations`, where you will see, that php parses `31/01/2015` as `American month, day and year` (format `m/d/Y`, and not `d/m/Y` as you are assuming). See [demo](https://eval.in/272638).

Your date format is custom, and you should treat it as one. Convert format to `/` to `.`, so the output date would be `31.01.2015`, which php will understand as `d.m.Y` format. See [demo](https://eval.in/272639).

IMHO, bet case would be to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), just tell to method what do you expect as input, like this:

```php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i:s A', $input);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/272642)**</kbd>

Comment: Your demo is not working.

Comment: @St3phan: can you show us your `$input` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this before your strtotime function:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York')
```

Here is an example from PHP.net:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

    $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

    if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
        echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
    } else {
        echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/test.php?process_time=31%2F01%2F2015+12%3A46%3A56+AM
here the my code
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo $process_time   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(urldecode($_REQUEST['process_time'])));

But not printing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$dt = "02/09/2015 11:33:22 AM";
$expDate = explode('/',$dt);
$newdate = $expDate[1]."/".$expDate[0]."/".$expDate[2];
$test = new DateTime($newdate);
echo date_format($test, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```